# logining via 3-party sites: what to use oauth or openid

Tags: php, oauth, openid

I need to develop a service that will perform login through several login providers (google, facebook, twitter and yahoo). Besides, I'll need to grab data from users profile (login, email, birhday and etc). Still I can't catch: is it better to use OAuth or OpenID (where it's posible) for that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you should learn each API's...

Comment: @rjmcb,but why?I can login through google an yahoo (and through other openid providers) by using one openid lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is to let users to login using various providers such as google, facebook etc and if you only need to grab profile information such as email, full name, county, language etc, Then OpenID is the best and the simple way to do it. That is the widely seeing use case of OpenID.
But if you are willing to interact with those providers such as to post in user's facebook wall etc, then go for OAuth. OAuth allows you to perform operations on those providers on behalf of the user.